# How to populate lightning:select with picklist field values?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, picklist, lightning-design-system, selectlist

Everything I have read online so far suggests that one must manually declare picklist (option) values when creating a `lightning:select` component in an Lightning application. For us, this is less than ideal.

Before I throw in the towel on this idea, I thought I'd ask Stack Exchange. Is it possible yet to have a `lightning:select` component automatically populate with options declared in the bound field's picklist values?

Comment: I think you're looking for lightning:inputField instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic method today is to get the values from the server, then render the values with $A.createComponents.

```
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
  var action = component.get("c.init");
  action.setParams({ ... });
  action.setCallback(this, function(result) {
    var options = [];
    result.getReturnValue().values.forEach(
      function(value) {
        options.push(['option', { label: value, value: value }]);
      });
    $A.createComponents(
      options,
      function(components) {
        component.find("mypicklist").set("v.options", components);
      });
    });
  $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

If that's too complicated, then you might consider using `lightning:inputField`, which is designed to work with `lightning:recordEditForm`.

There's no way to get `lightning:select` automatically populate with the options when bound to a field.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. Here's a link describing what the server-side code would look like: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2008/12/using-the-metadata-api-to-retrieve-picklist-values.html

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I populate `lightning:select` with picklist values:

1) create a server-side method that returns list of all picklist values available

2) call this method when lightning component is initialized

3) iterate through list of picklist options using `<aura:iteration>` inside `<lightning:select>` and add each of them as `<option>`

Don't have exact examples behind, but this approach works just fine.